# JQuery unobtrusive validation post form immediately after message shows

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have installed latest versions of all required libraries.

I have load scripts in layout header like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

And BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));
```

The problem I am facing is when I submit a form it shows error messages but post the form immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by replacing following line in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:

Replace this:

```
var $forms = $(selector).parents("form").andSelf().add($(selector).find("form")).filter("form");
```

With this:

```
var $forms = $(selector).parents("form").addBack().add($(selector).find("form")).filter("form");
```